# Data validation does not seem to work

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which in 7th column consists of statennames.

When I print the relevant column of the dataset by doing this:

```
outcome <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
x <- outcome[, 7]
y <- unique(x)
```

I get the unique values for the 7th column.

I now would like to make a validation in a formula which checks whether the value I enter is in the list.

So I created this function:

```
 name_in_list <- function(state) {
data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses="character")

if((state %in% data$state) == FALSE) {
 stop("invalid outcome")
}
print("succes!")
 }
```

Which, I think should check whether the value of the state is in there. But when I enter:

```
name_in_list("AL") I get ->  in name_in_list("AL") : invalid outcome
```

This is strange cause I think it should evaluate to true (and should evaluate to "succes!") because AL is in the dataset. Printing the unique values gives me:

```
"AL" "AK" "AZ" "AR" "CA" "CO" "CT" "DE" "DC" "FL" "GA" "HI" "ID" "IL" "IN" "IA" "KS" "KY" "LA" "ME" "MD" "MA" "MI" "MN" "MS" "MO" "MT" "NE" "NV" "NH" "NJ" "NM" "NY" "NC" "ND"
[36] "OH" "OK" "OR" "PA" "PR" "RI" "SC" "SD" "TN" "TX" "UT" "VT" "VI" "VA" "WA" "WV" "WI" "WY" "GU"
```

Any clues on what goes wrong?

Comment: It looks like somehow the "AL" state is not in the data set. Can you try putting 'print(data$state)' in that function immediately after the 'read.csv' line?

Comment: If your csv file is the identically named one given [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahawker/data-analysis-coursera/master/HW3/outcome-of-care-measures.csv) from a coursera course, it looks like you need `data$State` as the column name is capitalised, and `data$state` will give `NULL`

Comment: Thanks @ping that was it! A small type. Devil is in the details...

Comment: See if shortening works too `if(!state %in% data$State) stop('invalid'); print('success')`

Comment: Having a small utility function that reads in data from a flat file every time you use it is not good practice. It's like have instructions for baking a cake where the first step is "go to the grocery store on 1st Ave and buy eggs". It's better to pass in the data frame to the function, or even count on it being in the global environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
test_names <- function(x, dfc) ifelse(all(dfc %in% approved), TRUE, FALSE)
test_names(state, data$state)
```

But if you want a more recent solution that uses pipes and [a package designed for this purpose](https://github.com/tonyfischetti/assertr#assertr):

```
library(assertr)
library(dplyr)
# install with install.packages(c('assertr', 'dplyr')) 

# List your approved states in a vector
# or just read the unique values into one
approved_species <- c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor")
iris %>% 
  assert(in_set(approved_species), Species) %>% 
  # now perform some operation
  count(Species)
```

But if we shorten the approved list

```
approved_species <- c("setosa", "virginica")
iris %>% 
  assert(in_set(approved_species), Species) %>% 
  count(Species)
```

The operation fails because the data validation step failed. Does this help? Obviously you would swap out species with states for your dataset.